# Using Combine to Detect Username and Email Validity in Real Time in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am currently trying out the Combine framework in my authentication code in SwiftUI. I want the page to be when new users sign up if they enter a username and email and phone number that's not valid in terms of uniqueness (as in it's been used before), then the appropriate error messages would show along with a red X on each of the text fields that have the errors. Then, when the new user reenters text into said fields, once verified as valid the fields go from having a red X to a green check and the user moves on to the next page of the signing process. As of right now, everything works as intended except for the last part.

Here is the relevant code:

`SignUpView()`

```
struct SignUpView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SignUpViewViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .zero) {
                        UText("Signup", size: 24, type: .bold, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 16)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                            SegmentedProgressBar(totalSegments: 2, currentSegment: 1)
                                .frame(height: 10)
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text("Personal Information")
                                    .font(
                                        Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 18)
                                            .weight(.bold)
                                    )
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                Text("Step 1")
                                    .font(Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 14))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.68, blue: 1))
                            }
                            
                            // MARK: - TextFields (with Validity Checker)
                            
                            TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your name", text: $viewModel.name, isValid: true)
                            
                            TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your email", text: $viewModel.email, isValid: viewModel.isEmailValid)
                                .autocapitalization(.none)
                            if let errorEmailMessage = viewModel.errorEmailMessage {
                                UText(errorEmailMessage, size: 13, type: .light, color: .uLightRed)
                                    .padding(.top, -8)
                            }
                            
                            TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your username", text: $viewModel.username, isValid: viewModel.isUsernameValid)
                            if let errorUsernameMessage = viewModel.errorUsernameMessage {
                                UText(errorUsernameMessage, size: 13, type: .light, color: .uLightRed)
                                    .padding(.top, -8)
                            }
                            
                            SecureFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your password", text: $viewModel.password, isValid: CaseSensitivity.isValidPassword(viewModel.password))
                            
                            UText("Password must be 8 characters long with at least 1 number. No special characters.", size: 15, type: .medium, color: .white)
                                .padding(.top, -8)
                            
                            TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter phone number", text: $viewModel.phone, isValid: viewModel.isPhoneValid, keyboardType: .phonePad)
                            if let errorPhoneMessage = viewModel.errorPhoneMessage {
                                UText(errorPhoneMessage, size: 13, type: .light, color: .uLightRed)
                                    .padding(.top, -8)
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: SuggestedFollowersView(), isActive: $viewModel.navigateToSuggestedFollowers) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                if viewModel.isContinueButtonEnabled {
                                    viewModel.signUp()
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text("Continue")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .font(Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 18))
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .background(Color.primaryBlue)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                            .disableWithOpacity(!viewModel.isContinueButtonEnabled)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        .background {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                .fill(Color(red: 0.15, green: 0.17, blue: 0.22))
                                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 6)
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                        .inset(by: 0.5)
                                        .stroke(Color(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 1), lineWidth: 1)
                                )
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.containerBackground)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .tint(Color.uLabel)
                }))
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        NavLogo()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .colorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

`SignUpViewViewModel()`

```
class SignUpViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var signupState: SignupState
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var phone = ""
    @Published var navigateToSuggestedFollowers = false
    @Published var errorUsernameMessage: String?
    @Published var errorEmailMessage: String?
    @Published var errorPhoneMessage: String?
    @Published var isEmailValid: Bool = true
    @Published var isUsernameValid: Bool = true
    @Published var isPhoneValid: Bool = true
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    // MARK: - Continue Button will be locked until user fills all textfields, otherwise available to press
    
    var isContinueButtonEnabled: Bool {
        !name.isEmpty
        && !email.isEmpty
        && !username.isEmpty
        && !password.isEmpty
        && !phone.isEmpty
    }
    
    // Publishers for text field validation
    private var namePublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        $name
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var emailPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        $email
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var usernamePublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        $username
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var passwordPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        $password
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var phonePublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        $phone
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init(signupState: SignupState = SignupState()) {
        self.signupState = signupState
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.signupState = signupState
        }
        
        setupCombinePublishers()
    }
    
    private func setupCombinePublishers() {
        namePublisher
            .sink { _ in
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        emailPublisher
            .sink { _ in
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        usernamePublisher
            .sink { _ in
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        passwordPublisher
            .sink { _ in
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        phonePublisher
            .sink { _ in
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    private func validateEmail() {
        AuthService.shared.valid(email: email) { isValid, message in
            self.isEmailValid = isValid
            self.errorEmailMessage = isValid ? nil : message
        }
    }
    
    private func validateUsername() {
        AuthService.shared.valid(username: username) { isValid, message in
            self.isUsernameValid = isValid
            self.errorUsernameMessage = isValid ? nil : message
        }
    }
    
    private func validatePhone() {
        Task {
            do {
                let isValid = try await AuthService.shared.checkPhoneNumber(phone: phone)
                self.isPhoneValid = isValid
                self.errorPhoneMessage = isValid ? nil : "This phone number is associated with another account."
            } catch {
                print("Error validating phone: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Saves new user credentials to backend
    func signUp() {
        let accountData = AccountSignUp2(name: name, email: email, username: username, password: password, phone: phone)
        
        AuthService.shared.signup2(data: accountData) { result, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    debugPrint(error)
                    self.validateEmail()
                    self.validateUsername()
                    self.validatePhone()
                } else if result != nil {
                    print("SignUp Successful!")
                    self.navigateToSuggestedFollowers = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`TextFieldValidity()`

```
struct TextFieldValidity: View {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var isValid: Bool
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .alphabet

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                .keyboardType(keyboardType)
                .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.dismissKeyboard()
                }
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                        .inset(by: 0.5)
                        .stroke(Color(red: 0.22, green: 0.24, blue: 0.32), lineWidth: 1)
                )

            if !text.isEmpty {
                if isValid {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func dismissKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

What should I add or modify to ensure that when the user reenters credentials into the text fields whenever an error is found, the red X turns into a green check when everything is verified as valid? I tried using `.onChange()` with no luck. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Also, there's a lot of code in here that doesn't make any sense, like calling `objectWillChange` when a `@Published` value changes. That's redundant (since the first version of SwiftUI out of beta). I'd suggest you spend some time with the SwiftUI tutorials at Apple or Hacking with Swift to learn how the basics of the framework work.

Comment: I am new to Combine, so I am still learning it and getting used to it. I guess one example can be in ```TextFieldValidity```. If the fields aren't valid, they should get a red x, but the red x remains after the user reenters a valid input. I'm trying to have it such that once the new text is entered and verified as valid, the fields get a green check again.

Comment: Can you pare it down to a [mre] so that others can run the code?